Flutter Sqflite Database.execute(String sql, [List<Object?>? arguments]) not substituting arguments
I added database migration logic for sqflite database in a flutter app. It includes the following sql command:
db.execute("ALTER TABLE notes ADD COLUMN time TEXT DEFAULT ? NOT NULL", [currentTime])
Here db is of type Database and currentTime is of type String. 
When I run the app in an android device, I get the following execption:
error DatabaseException(near "?": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE notes ADD COLUMN time TEXT DEFAULT ? NOT NULL) sql 'ALTER TABLE notes ADD COLUMN time TEXT DEFAULT ? NOT NULL' args [2024-04-13 15:18:38.424054Z] during open, closing...
Why does sqflite not substitute the arguments that i provide along with sql parameter. Is there no secure way to use the execute funtion?
